# Why the method Distinct() does not working?

Tags: c#, discord

I am building a Discord Bot in C# (dsharpplus) and I get an error with the Distinct() method but I do not know why...

```
[Command("poll")]
    public async Task Poll(CommandContext ctx, TimeSpan duration, params DiscordEmoji[] emojiOptions)
    {
        var interactivity = ctx.Client.GetInteractivityModule();
        var options = emojiOptions.Select(x => x.ToString());

        var pollEmbed = new DiscordEmbedBuilder
        {
            Title = "Poll",
            Description = string.Join(" ", options)
        };

        var pollMessage = await ctx.Channel.SendMessageAsync(embed: pollEmbed).ConfigureAwait(false);

        foreach (var option in emojiOptions)
        {
            await pollMessage.CreateReactionAsync(option).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }

        var result = await interactivity.CollectReactionsAsync(pollMessage, duration).ConfigureAwait(false);

        var distinctResult = result.Distinct();

        var results = distinctResult.Select(x => $"{x.Emoji}: {x.Total}");

        await ctx.Channel.SendMessageAsync(string.Join("\n", results)).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
```

The error is " 'ReactionCollectionContext' does not contain a definition for 'Distinct' and no accessible extension method 'Distinct' accepting a first argument of type 'ReactionCollectionContext' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"
"
Am I doing something wrong here?
Help me, please!

Comment: What kind of error do you have here?

Comment: I just put it in the description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [sources](https://github.com/uwx/HSNXT.DSharpPlus/blob/951a546bab6d396e539c1a3606029ce17001220f/HSNXT.DSharpPlus.InteractivityNext/Entities/ReactionCollectionContext.cs) it looks like that your `result` is not a collection at all. Try to something like

```
result.Reactions.Distinct();
```

Comment: Ok! That works but now I have other 2 errors :))
' var results = distinctResult.Select(x => $"{x.Emoji}: {x.Total}");'
The errors are on Emoji and Total: " 'KeyValuePair<DiscordEmoji, int>' does not contain a definition for 'Total' and no accessible extension method 'Total' accepting a first argument of type 'KeyValuePair<DiscordEmoji, int>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)" and the same for the second error but for Emoji not for Total 
"

Comment: The `Reactions` is a dictionary, where the key is `DiscordEmoji` and value is count of reactions for selected emoji. So, you can just use such a data "as is", you do not need 'Total' and `Emoji'. So
``var results = distinctResult.Select(x => $"{x.Key}: {x.Value}");``

Comment: Moreover, as the `Reactions` is a `Dictionary`, you actually do not need to perform `Distinct` for it, as the `Dictionary` already guarantees that keys will be unique.